# beamer paralist issue : the patch is not working?

Tags: beamer, paralist

With this MWE :

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[flushleft,alwaysadjust]{paralist}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{compactenum}

\item essai

\end{compactenum}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I have the next error message :

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerpatchparalist.sty)
No file bob.nav.
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix 
                               item
l.11 \end{frame}
```

Comment: Packages such as `enumitem` and `paralist` are not compatible with `beamer`.

Comment: @egreg they were compatible until I update from tl 2017 to tl 2018. I use both packages together in this configuration for at least 4 years.

Comment: The fact that they *seemed* to work with `beamer` is not evidence they actually did.

Comment: I aggree with you, I'm just surprised that it is now less compatible than before. I recompiled a file I usually use without problem and it stucked. I'll use Sam Carter solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The patch seems to patch only "normal" lists like `enumerate`, `itemize` or `description`. If I understand the `paralist` code correctly, a `compactenum` is basically the same as a normal `enumerate`, just with adjusted spaces. You could do this manually:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[flushleft,alwaysadjust]{paralist}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{enumerate}
\parsep\plparsep
\itemsep\plitemsep
\topsep\pltopsep
\partopsep\plpartopsep
\item essai
\item essai
\end{enumerate}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```